# jQuery selector help get the last element of several groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this type of html

```
<div id='foo'>
  <ol>
   <li>
      <a/>
      <a/>
      <ol><li><a/><a/><a/></li></ol>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a/>
      <a/>
      <ol><li><a/><a/><a/></li></ol>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a/>
      <a/>
      <ol><li><a/><a/><a/></li></ol>
   </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

How can I select just the last 'a' tag in each first level 'li'?  I tried using :last but I only get the very last 'a'.  Note I do not want the 'a' elements that are nested inside the nested 'ol's. I.E. The selector should yield 3 'a' tags. Any tips or examples would be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: +1 for good question. Though I think it would help if you replace the `<a/>` tags you expect to get returned with `<a>last one</a>`. Saves a lot of answers randomly posting first-thoughts.

Comment: If jQuery supported `:last-of-type` you could use `#foo > ol > li > a:last-of-type`

Comment: Love the simplicity of `atx's` answer though using a fully supported selector.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#foo > ol > li > a:last-of-type');`

You also have to use the child selector between li and a otherwise it will return all a elements that are a last-child.

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/48uQM/3/

updated my answer to use red background color so its easier to see.

As its been mentioned in the comments, this will not work in IE8 or older or any browser that does not support :last-of-type

**To work in IE8 and older browsers here is another solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/zcH8D/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $li = $('#foo > ol > li');
    $li.each(function () {
      $a = $(this).find(">a");
      $a.filter(":last").addClass('last');                
    });        
});​
```

Comment: `last-of-type` will only work if the browser supports it natively.

Comment: +1 as your last edit works now, bearing in mind `Musa's` comment. Consider updating your fiddle though to use something similar to `atx`'s `.css('background-color', 'red');` It makes it clearer what is being matched.

Comment: @Musa that would be an issue for IE8 and older.

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
$("div ol li ol").prev().css('background-color', 'red');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4vYq/)

Comment: +1, According to OP: `How can I select just the last 'a' tag in each first level 'li'?` and `The selector should yield 3 'a' tags.` Unless OP updates what 3 exactly are expected to be returned this answer looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo > ol > li > a').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).next('a').length
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mBwug/

Comment: No this does not work. Omar Jackman's answer is correct (it was before he edited lol).  This selector #foo ol > li > a:last only returns the very last 'a'.  #foo > ol> li:last-child > a:last-child did return the correct results

Comment: +1, this answer does the trick now too. Though it is clearer what is matched when using `.css('background-color', 'red');` instead of `.text('selected')`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#foo>ol>li a:last-child');
```

will get you the last a tag within the first level li element

etc.

Comment: its a pretty simple answer. Did you see a typo?

Comment: Question was: How can I select just the last 'a' tag in each **first level** 'li'? Yours seems to look for the last li tag... not first

Comment: @Omar Jackman: I see that it won't return what OP asked. Read the question once again, open jsfiddle.net and check your code

Comment: Omar your first answer was correct before you edited. #foo > ol> li:last-child > a:last-child

Comment: @Hcabnettek: how is it correct? http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/PrYwq/ It returns empty result set

Comment: you're right. Not sure why I changed it to last from last-child. I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
​//console.log($('ol li ol li a:last'))

var lists = $('ol li ol li'); 
$.each(lists, function(i){
    console.log($(this).find('a:last'))
});
​
```

Without a loop you can try this

```
 console.log($('ol li ol li > a:last-child');)
```

[FIDDLE No LOOP](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/JUtb7/2/)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/JUtb7/)

Comment: just one selector no looping. Thanks tho =)

Comment: @zerkms: It still doesn;t return all of them. Pointless to +1 the least incorrect answer,...no?

Comment: @François Wahl: I upvoted because it doesn't deserve to be downvoted. When it was posted - it was the only one that respected the "last a" requirement from the question. So this answerer was the most attentive to the original question text. And even now - it still returns the correct result (not in one object though)

Comment: @zerkms: None of the selectors or fiddles return the correct results. So upvoting it makes no sense. They all return the last a tag in the most inner li tag instead of the last a tag in the first level li tag. Use the selectors on `atx`s or `Mark`'s fiddle which will visually show it.